# Why Fe(OH)2 and some precipitates do not dissolve in excess ammonia?

Tags: coordination-compounds

I understand that Cu(OH)2 can dissolve in excess ammonia because ligand exchange reaction occurs. But why ligand exchange reaction does not occur for Fe(OH)2?